# Unable to display error message in a react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to show error messages like `Incorrect password` as an alert or toast when the user enters the wrong password.

[image: screenshot when checkForLoginError function gets called]

So, this is the error that I'm getting in the console. In `checkForLoginError` function `this.props.auth.authError` is null for the first time. That's why I'm getting this error. And to actually show the message `Incorrect password`, I had to click again on the submit button, as you can see in the screenshot.

---

Here's the code.

**loginUser controller**

```js
 loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      console.log("inside login controller")
      const { email, password } = req.body
      if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
      }
      if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
      }
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "This email does not exist" })
      }
      if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
        // console.log("Password in login controller", password)
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect password" })
      }

      res.status(200).json({ user })
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

**Login.js**

```js
mport React, { Component } from "react"
import validator from "validator"
import { loginUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { toastError } from "../../utils/toastify"

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }



  checkForLoginError = () => {
    console.log("inside checkForLoginError")
    console.log(this.props.auth.authError)
    if (this.props.auth.authError !== null) {
      const authError = this.props.auth.authError.response.data.message
      console.log(authError)
      if (authError === null) {
        this.props.history.push("/")
      } else {
        return toastError(authError)
      }
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { email, password } = this.state

    const loginData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }

    if (!email || !password) {
      return toastError("Email and password are must.")
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Password must contain 6 characters.")
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      return toastError("Invalid email.")
    }

    this.props.dispatch(loginUser(loginData, this.checkForLoginError()))
  }

  render() {
    const isAuthInProgress = this.props.auth.isAuthInProgress
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className=Also, is there a need for similar checks like I have done both in controller and the component like `if (!email || !password)` and `if (!validator.isEmail(email))`. Or should it be only in the backend?
"control">
            {isAuthInProgress ? (
              <button className="button is-success is-loading">Login</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
                Login
              </button>
            )}
          </p>
        </div>
        <Link to="/forgot-password">
          <p className="has-text-danger">Forgot password?</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm)
```

**loginUser action creator**

```js
export const loginUser = (loginData, redirect) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/users/login`, loginData)
      console.log(res.data)
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_SUCCESS",
        data: { user: res.data.user }
      })
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", res.data.token)
      redirect()
      toastSuccess("You are now logged in!")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_ERROR",
        data: { error },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**auth reducer**

```js
const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        authError: null,
      }

    case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: null,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isIdentifyingToken: false,
        user: action.data.user,
      }

    case "AUTH_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: action.data.error,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your ask, I am giving my input. Please ignore if it is not that what you are seeking.

When you get 401 unauthorized error in checkForLoginError then instead of redirecting the user through this.props.history.push('/'), you can return a Modal on condition of authError = true which will show Incorrect Password.

On the button click on above Modal, you can then redirect the user using this.props.history.push('/').

Comment: I'm getting 401 becuase I'm typing the wrong password. It's what I expect. But what I don't expect is that the error message doesn't show up as I hit the submit button. I have to click again to show it. It's probably because `this.props.auth.authError` is null for the first time.